# loss function for stopping problem

Tags: modeling, loss-functions, optimal-stopping

I want to test different algorithms for **predicting when a person stops an activity**. The information available to the person (and the algorithms) consists of different performance criteria and other variables. I wonder which loss function to use for describing how far off an algorithm is.

**One possibility** is a continuous loss function, such as MSE. When the person continues beyond the point that algorithm predicts as a stopping point, this would work. In the reverse case, beyond the stopping point, the algorithms have no information for creating a prediction about the stopping point.

**A second possibility** is to use binary decisions at different points before the person stops: "continue" and "stop". I could then calculate for each algorithm the proportion of decision points at which it predicts correctly. In this case, there is only small room for imrovement over a naive strategy that always predicts "continue" would be always correct, except for the last point at which the person stops.

Is anyone aware of (other) valid loss functions for such problems?

Comment: Surely the desirability of various possible loss functions depend on the intended use of the analytical results. Is this question a generic one or specific for an actual purpose?

Comment: The purpose of the analysis is to describe the person's behavior. The loss function is supposed to capture the quality of this description for different algorithms, to identify the one that predicts best.

Comment: Would the algorithm that is exactly correct more often be best, or an algorithm that is nearly correct more often? Is an error of 2 units twice as bad as an error of 4 units? Is an error in the positive direction equally bad as an error of the same amount in the other direction? You can make any arbitrary function of distance between prediction and real stopping time, so you have to decide. They are all "valid".

Comment: The problem is that after the point at which the person stops, the algorithm cannot generate predictions anymore. So for this case, the exact stopping point is unknown. In the reverse case (that is, when the algorithm predicts "stop" too early), I can see that all kinds of loss functions would work but the first case confuses me.